# QTabWidget styling - missing the bottom of my 'g...s'

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

I currently have the following style-sheet for my QtabWidget

```
QTAB

QTabWidget
{
  /*   min-width:5000em;*/
}


 QTabWidget::tab-bar 
{
     left: 5px; /* move to the right by 5px */
 }


 QTabWidget::pane
 {
     border-top: 1px solid gray;
     border-left: 1px solid gray;
     border-right: 1px solid gray;
     border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 }

 QTabBar::tab
 {
     background-color: rgb(166, 166, 166);
     min-width: 70px;

     padding-top : 6px;
     padding-bottom : 8px;
     color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     font: 10pt "Arial";
 }

 QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover 
{
     background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
 }

 QTabBar::tab:selected 
{
     /*border-color: #9B9B9B;*/
 }

 QTabBar::tab:!selected
 {
     margin-top: 2px; /* make non-selected tabs look smaller */

 }
```

This results in something like this

[image]

I wanted to know how I can fix the bottom of my 'g's as they seem to be cut off  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add more room by adjusting the values within this part:

```
QTabBar::tab
{
    background-color: rgb(166, 166, 166);
    min-width: 70px;

    padding-top : 6px;
    padding-bottom : 8px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: 10pt "Arial";
}
```

for example adding a minimum height that accommodates enough room for your text, also there is a problem with padding here just remove the lines `padding-top: 6px` and `padding-bottom:  8px`:

```
QTabBar::tab
{
    background-color: rgb(166, 166, 166);
    min-width: 70px;

    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: 10pt "Arial";
}
```

[here](http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=17497) is the result of my compilation. I didn't have enough reputation points to post an Image.